# Little tiny black stripes on external display

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, external-display

So I've got a laptop, and a Samsung T24D390 24' connected to it via HDMI. I use the bigger screen ofc. as my primary. Now today I've noticed tiny black stripes at the top and at the right of my display. They look like this:

[image]

For the purpose of comparing, there is a photo of the same window fullscreened on my laptop display:

[image]

I've updated intel drivers, I even checked on my dual booted Linux installation, it's the same, so I guess its not a drivers problem. I've searched through the internet, but I couldn't quite find an answer to this. Have you guys faced a problem like this, or know the solution for it?

P.S I checked Speccy, it shows me something like this:

[image]

So there is a difference between Current Resolution and the Work resolution, but it's the same on my laptop display (the second shown in Speccy) and its okay, so I guess it's not a problem too.

Comment: Do you have the laptop open so that it is extending the desktop to both screens? When this happens, the monitor tends to use the same resolution as the laptop.

Comment: Yes, I do. And it doesn't, cuz I changed it